# Remove color table from TIFF in QGIS 3.8 because virtual raster does not work due to color table issue

Tags: qgis

I have a set of 14 rasters that I would like to create a virtual raster (vrt) from. When I create the vrt one of the rasters does not appear in the new file. The raster have identical formats except the missing one displays [image: Band 1 (Gray)] in the layer styling box and the others show [image: Band 1 (Palette)]. It seems like this is due to the missing one not having a color table or palette where as the others do. I have gotten around this by creating a vrt of the tif without the color palette, opening the vrt with a text editor  and changing `<ColorInterp>Gray</ColorInterp>`  to `<ColorInterp>Palette</ColorInterp>` and then creating a vrt with the other 13 and the hacked vrt.

Is there a way I could instead convert the file to have a color table or better remove the color table from the others? 
From my tests warp does not strip the color table.

Answer (score 2):

Inside QGIS you can use `Raster-> Conversion -> PCT to RGB`, or you can use the [GDAL](https://gdal.org) Utility [`pct2rgb`](https://gdal.org/programs/pct2rgb.html#pct2rgb) to convert the palette to a rgb image.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't test this. I couldn't get that to work with my file. I get a AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetCount' error. I want to end up with a single band file wouldn't this give me a 3 band file?

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to remove the palette with gdal_translate https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html by using the option `-expand gray`. Try and tell if it works, the documentation is a bit cryptical.

> -expand gray|rgb|rgba
>
> To expose a dataset with 1 band with a color table as a dataset with 3 (RGB) or 4 (RGBA) bands. Useful for output
>   drivers such as JPEG, JPEG2000, MrSID, ECW that don’t support color
>   indexed datasets. The ‘gray’ value enables to expand a dataset with a
>   color table that only contains gray levels to a gray indexed dataset.

Comment: It seems the QGIS 3.8 dialog for Translate does not have the ability to add additional command line options so I was unable to try this.

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved this was by running GDAL merge with only one file and **Grab pseudocolor table from first layer** unchecked. This gets rid of the color table.